# Pentaho report designer uppercase a fields

Tags: pentaho, uppercase, pentaho-report-designer

I'm using Pentaho report designer 5.2 and 6.0
I have a field which contains translations from the resource-file from our DB.
All our translations are lowercased and I want to put some uppercases in my report. For example the first letter of a word.

How would I do this? I can't find any information on Pentaho forums about it.
Nor an option in style/attributes in PRD itself.

Answer (score 0):

is required to do so in report??, can do this by building the field as prayer using SQL, thus would not have to do anything in the report, only use the field, here I leave an example of how you might do it in SQL, this based on the data source sample data, the explanation would be the siquiguiente, take the first character and took him to uppercase, this will concatenate with the rest of the chain and that's it, hope you serve, sorry for my English, esta rusty , regards 
the example:

```
SELECT
 "DEPARTMENT_MANAGERS"."REGION",
 "DEPARTMENT_MANAGERS"."MANAGER_NAME",
 concat(upper(substr(EMAIL ,1,1)),substr(EMAIL,2,length(EMAIL))) FROM
 "DEPARTMENT_MANAGERS"
```

Comment: yea it's kind of required to do so in the report :(

Comment: you cant do the same i did with sql using formula, go to tab Data and add new Open Formula (Advanced) and the formula to do that you want is this: =CONCATENATE(UPPER(LEFT([EMAIL];1));MID([EMAIL];2;LEN([EMAIL]))), you cant use it,regards